# Error unknown configuration variable 'advanced-telemetry'

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4, flash-builder

I'm trying to use [Scout](http://gaming.adobe.com/technologies/scout/?promoid=KBQHD) with my Flex project and to do that I heard that you add  -advanced-telemetry to the compiler arguments. When I do that get this error:

Error unknown configuration variable 'advanced-telemetry'

Am I doing this right or am I missing something?

Comment: UPDATE: If you use an Apache Flex SDK release you should be able to add this compiler option but I have not tested it myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found I can add in advanced telemetry after the fact with the [Scout Enabler](http://renaun.com/blog/2012/12/enable-advanced-telemetry-on-flex-or-old-swfs-with-swf-scount-enabler/) tool.

Testing a browser based app:

1. After compiling the SWF to a release build I dragged it from the project release folder and dropped it on the Scout Enabler. Scout enabler provided a message that it was converted successfully. NOTE: Scout Enabler will add a prefix or suffix and if the HTML page you are using doesn't reference that project-suffix.swf file then it won't load. I just leave the suffix text field empty so my project swf is always myProject.swf (not myProject-scout.swf).
2. Open Scout if it's not already open.
3. Load the SWF in the browser (or actually the HTML wrapper page that loads your swf).
4. Go back to Scout and you'll see it enabled.

[More info](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/scout/articles/adobe-scout-getting-started.html)

Note: It doesn't appear to work with the iOS simulator but does work with the AIR simulator.

**UPDATE:**
As others have pointed out it now works with Apache Flex release 4.10 and newer but has [issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26918015/441016). Workarounds in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from [adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flashbuilder/using/WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4798e7bb139e879b36f-8000.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb5-4798e7bb139e879b36f-7ffe); "the advanced telemetry options are available only for ActionScript projects and ActionScript Mobile projects that use the ActionScript Compiler 2.0 (ASC 2.0)"

The ASC 2.0 compiler is included in recent AIR SDKs (from 3.4 i think?) - if you overlay latest AIR SDK (3.6) over flex sdk, you should be able to use the advanced telemetry in AS3-only projects.

Unfortunately, ASC 2.0 does not work with MXML (yet) so we are stuck for now.

Comment: I tried to overlay with the compiler and this is what happened, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885218/could-not-resolve-ssequence-to-a-component-implementation-after-adding-air-3#comment20935800_14885218

Comment: ive had issues too with pre-existing projects. open .actionScriptProperties file for project and change useFlashSDK="false" to useFlashSDK="true" (or could be the other way round?)

Comment: ..but you're using flex so you cant use ASC2.0 and cant use advanced telemetry

Comment: There aren't any plans for ASC 2 to support MXML but I've found you can add it in later. I'll post below.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to use FlashBuilder with Flex to build a desktop AIR package, you will get this error because the Flex compiler is older and does not know about -advanced-telemetry. The problem is, you need to package your SWF into an AIR file so you need to get at the SWF after it is built but before it gets packaged. Here is a trick to do that.

When you export a release build, proceed though the dialogs, but before you hit "finish" on the last dialog, find the bin-release-temp folder in your project and use SWFScoutEnabler to add advanced telemetry to the swf in that folder. Then hit finish and you will have an AIR package with a Scout enabled SWF.

Answer (score 2):

Support for advanced telemetry was added in Apache Flex 4.10.

Comment: There's actually problem with this if you're using Flash Builder 4.7 to export a release build. And that's for a release build only. It works with a debug build.  You'll get a null pointer. The solution by Gavin is what you'd need to do.  Or use adt.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the `-advanced-telemetry` compiler option to Flash Builder (Bungler?) has caused me two weird problems.

1. When exporting a release build I get this error "Flash Builder could not publish the project source: null"
2. Code hints, outline view, immediately stop working.

The only solution I could find was Grants work around by enabling advanced telemetry on the swfs in bin-debug and bin-release-temp before packaging it into an ipa file.