# "Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without the new compiler."?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex4

I am confused about upgrading AIR for use with Flex 4.6 (I am using 4.6 because "design mode" isn't supported in Flash Build with later versions).

I successfully overlaid AIR 19 on a copy of the Flex 4.6 SDK. Some projects were fine but others were not. For example the `<mx:Alert/>` is not supported (apparently) in AIR 19 by default and I resolved that by linking to the `mx.swf`

In another project I am finding that `<s:ConstraintRow/>` is not supported. Searching around I found this question: [Could not resolve <s:Sequence> to a component implementation after adding AIR 3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14885218/could-not-resolve-ssequence-to-a-component-implementation-after-adding-air-3)

So, ok – I see the note I missed before on the AIR 19 page: ["Flex users will need to download the original AIR SDK without the new compiler."](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/air-sdk-download.html)

**My Questions:**

- What is the "original" AIR SDK? What version is that? Is this just poor wording and means "the latest AIR without the AS compiler 2.0" Or is Flex deadended for AIR upgrades?
- What is the deal with AIR version
  numbers? I see both "AIR 19" and "AIR 3.4" etc. which seems like two different numbering schemes.

Comment: New Version Numbering fromm 11/14/2013 :http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2013/11/new-version-numbering-2.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok – I think I have answered at least one of my questions.

It seems the term "original" in the Adobe comment means "latest AIR release *without* the AS Compiler 2.0"* as I was able to download the "original" version of AIR listed on that page and overlay it on Flex 4.6 without project errors resulting.

<s>Still don't understand the version numbering with AIR.</s> @RobertN helpfully provided a link explaining the version numbering: [Adobe AIR and Adobe Flash Player Team Blog](http://blogs.adobe.com/flashplayer/2013/11/new-version-numbering-2.html)

And yes, that's another hour of my work life with Flex that I can't bill for. Thanks Adobe. . .